# SQLAlchemy - query without writing/locking the database

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, permissions, sqlalchemy

I have a multithreaded data analysis pipeline, which queries a database (via SQLAlchemy). Additionally, the database is synchronized across multiple systems by syncthing - long story short, this means that write permission cannot always be guaranteed.

Even when I am able to guarantee write access, I still occasionally and rather randomly get operational errors:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked
```

The code I use to load the session for the query is the following:

```
def loadSession(db_path):
    db_path = "sqlite:///" + path.expanduser(db_path)
    engine = create_engine(db_path, echo=False)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    return session, engine
```

And can be seen in its full context [here](https://github.com/TheChymera/LabbookDB/blob/master/labbookdb/db/query.py#L171).

My query (and the way I turn it into a value) look like this:

```
    session, engine = loadSession(db_path)
    sql_query=session.query(LaserStimulationProtocol).filter(LaserStimulationProtocol.code==stim_protocol_dictionary[scan_type])
    mystring = sql_query.statement
    mydf = pd.read_sql_query(mystring,engine)
    delay = int(mydf["stimulation_onset"][0])
```

And again, the full context can be found [here](https://github.com/IBT-FMI/SAMRI/blob/master/samri/pipelines/extra_functions.py#L171).

How could I change my code so the database can be queried without having to rely on the file being writeable/unlocked? I have checked the file's checksum, and it does not change upon query, so clearly I'm not writing anything to it. As such, I guess there should be some way to extract the info I am looking for without write access?

Answer (score -1):

I've written a blog post on the subject which provides some more explanation of the issue and some ways to work around it: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/multi-threaded-sqlite-without-the-operationalerrors/

Peewee ORM has an extension that is designed to support multiple threads writing to a SQLite database. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#sqliteq

Comment: Regarding the downvote, I understand if you're not interested in using Peewee -- the blog post goes into detail about the intricacies of locking and transaction management with SQLite, though, and applies regardless of what ORM you're using (or not using).

Comment: The downvoter here, I apologize for not leaving a comment before, something came up that required attention. As to why, I've nothing against Peewee. The reason was that this is pretty much a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). I understand that you might be uninterested in quoting yourself here, but it'd serve this site better, if users did not need to follow the links in order to get the basics. The answer itself should, well, answer and hold links to further reading. Also, link rot is a thing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying -- I appreciate the constructive feedback (and the downvote seems fair). Thanks again!